# Python: pytz returning unusable __repr__()

Tags: python, instance, representation, pytz

I understand that `repr()`'s purpose is to return a string, that can be used to be evaluated as a python command and return the same object. Unfortunately, `pytz` does not seem to be very friendly with this function, although it should be quite easy, since `pytz` instances are created with a single call:

```
import datetime, pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
repr(now)
```

returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 2, 17, 659333, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

which cannot be simply copied to another ipython windows and evaluated, because it returns a Syntax Error on the `tzinfo` attribute.

Is there any simple way to let it print:

```
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 2, 17, 659333, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

when the `'Europe/Berlin'` string is already clearly visible in the original output of `repr()`?

Comment: is it always going to be `Europe/Berlin` or will it be arbitrary timezone?

Comment: It can be any timezone. I want a pythonic representation of a datetime object that I can copy&paste&execute in an ipython shell and get the original timestamp with its timezone. So no global converting to UTC please.

Comment: FYI: It is recommended that `repr` be usable to reproduce the object, but it is not required.

Comment: @Daenyth: if it is recommended, then it would be nice if the developers of such common libraries would use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pytz.tzinfo

def tzinfo_repr(self):
    return 'pytz.timezone({z})'.format(z=self.zone)
pytz.tzinfo.DstTzInfo.__repr__=tzinfo_repr

berlin=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
now = datetime.datetime.now(berlin)
print(repr(now))
# datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 39, 4, 456039, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin"))
```

Note that `pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")` in the summer can mean something different than `pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin"))` in the winter, due to daylight savings time. So the monkeypatched `__repr__` is not a correct representation of `self` for all time. But it should work (except for extreme corner cases) during the time it takes to copy and paste into IPython.

---

An alternative approach would be to subclass `datetime.tzinfo`:

```
class MyTimezone(datetime.tzinfo):
    def __init__(self,zone):
        self.timezone=pytz.timezone(zone)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyTimezone("{z}")'.format(z=self.timezone.zone)
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.timezone._utcoffset
    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.timezone._tzname
    def dst(self, dt):
        return self.timezone._dst

berlin=MyTimezone('Europe/Berlin')
now = datetime.datetime.now(berlin)
print(repr(now))
# datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 1, 19, 2, 58, 702758, tzinfo=MyTimezone("Europe/Berlin"))
```

Comment: Looks like what I wanted, although doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: Subclassing isn't really portable (to send someone quickly a datetime(...) constructor call line per email), but it is probably the easiest solution for local usage in ipython. Thank you!

Comment: It looks horrible, but have you considered sending pickled objects, e.g. `import cPickle; cPickle.loads("cdatetime\ndatetime\np1\n(S'\\x07\\xda\\n\\x01\\x151+\\x0c\\x13\\xd0'\ncpytz\n_p\np2\n(S'Europe/Berlin'\np3\nI7200\nI3600\nS'CEST'\np4\ntRp5\ntRp6\n.")`

Comment: No, because it looks horrible and I want to be able to read the line too. I am thinking about contacting pytz developpers and asking them whether their __repr__ could be changed...

Comment: Please note the `__repr__` is supposed to give enough information to re-generate the object. Setting `__repr__` to return `"pytz.timezone(...)"` fails because it ignores the day-light savings time issue.

Comment: How does it ignore the DST issue?  Whether DST was in effect is based on the time, which the object contains... and whether DST was in effect in Oct 2010 is in the tzinfo (yup, it contains historical start/end dates of DST too.  At least the Olson db does).

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: Using `datetime(..., tzinfo=pytz.timezone(...))` is almost never the correct way to make a timezone-aware datetime. [`pytz` expects you to use its localize or astimezone method](http://pythonhosted.org//pytz/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic). Even though `pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')` knows about the DST transition boundaries, when you use `datetime(..., tzinfo=...)` that information is ignored and it simply uses the *first* timezone in `pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')`.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: For example, `DT.datetime(2015, 5, 4, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))` returns `datetime.datetime(..., tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' LMT+0:53:00 STD>)`, when it should return `datetime.datetime(..., tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Berlin' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)`